# Ms access query to retrieve required value only

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2007

How to retrieve value from database suppose

districtname = Lucknow H.O
now, using access I need to know how to retrieve value only by search on the first six letter i.e user query Lucknow H.O or any bigger space string and database check by query till Lucknow after that any letter allowed for match, i need a code help which wok with any kind of name how much its lenght space it only look for first 6 letters, I have used sql where I use % but I am not able to use it in ms access please help

I have problem with this code I got error

Comment: Please provide your code that caused the error and the error you received

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send search Pointer to start in MS access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804866/send-search-pointer-to-start-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 1):

MS Access SQL uses non-standard wildcard characters. Try LIKE 'Lucknow*'.

Comment: how can here if city taken value from form type text                 strSQL = "Select pincode from pincodes WHERE Districtname = '" & city & "' AND officename = '" & area &"';"